# Loading LTKs timed out for hci0

Tags: bluetooth, connection, ubuntu-20.04

Because of **Loading LTKs timed out for hci0** I cannot connect to bluetooth using
bluetoothctl command.

```
$ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-25 16:20:40 IST; 2min 54s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 12417 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6932)
     Memory: 620.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─12417 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Starting SDP server
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.118 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 25 16:20:40 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.118 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 25 16:20:43 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Jan 25 16:20:51 Painkiller bluetoothd[12417]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

From **rfkill** command we can say the **bluetooth** device is not **blocked**?

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Bluetoothctl** command to connect to my **airpods**. I have stopped and restarted by bluetooth several times but still I cannot connect to my airpods.

```
$ bluetoothctl connect BB:91:C0:4E:22:EF
Attempting to connect to BB:91:C0:4E:22:EF
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
```

What is the meaning of Loading **LTKs timed out for hci0** error and how to **resolve** it?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, solved this way:

```
 rmmod btusb
 modprobe btusb
```

[Reference](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171357)